# Term Server users have long delay when browsing files

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

Users are logging into one of three 2003 Terminal Servers. This problem is only for the users logging in and doesn't effect if an Admin account logs in. I'll try to describe the problem.

When the user clicks on My Computer the screen pops up and then the flight light will appear. This will stay up for about 10 seconds, then if they they click on any drive to browse further it will go to the next screen and then a hourglass will appear. The amount of time this takes to load can be anywhere from 10 seconds to 2 minutes. The problem is more apparent on the network shares but like I said if I am logged in as a admin there is no delay. Any idea what could be causing this?

If there is any other details you need to help me on this let me know and I will add it below.

Comment: Update - It seems that this does effect all users. The slow browser only happens once I open a file on the network drive. After I do this moving around in explorer is extremely slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you redirecting local drives to the TS sessions? If so, try disabling that and see if it improves the perfomance.

If you are redirecting local drives to the TS session then Windows Explorer has to enumerate those drives and that can take awhile, dependent on the quality of the network connection between the client and the server.

Comment: Local drives are getting redirected but if I login as an admin user this slow effect is not there but if I login as one of the general users the effect shows up. Here is another twist... I made a new user and there is no issue as well.

Comment: I tried with out local drives as well and same result